# With self signed certificate, curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, curl, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

I have created a self signed certificate using `keytool`. Full command is

```
keytool -keystore server.p12 -alias server_key -keyalg rsa -ext ku=DigitalSignature,keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment
```

I added this keystore to my web server as well. There was no there. My question is about how to curl to the server without skipping verification. (I don't want to use `-k` option). I exported the server certificate using the following command

```
keytool -export -keystore server.p12 -alias server_key -file server.crt
```

With `curl -v --cacert server.crt https://host:port`, the following is the error even though server certificate is provided for curl.

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:5443/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/innsh/Downloads/cacert.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: If a selfsigned cert (i.e. used both as EE and pseudo-CA) has **KU/KeyUsage it MUST include keyCertSign**. Also it should have BC/BasicConstraints with ca:true but for SSL/TLS including HTTPS, which you appear to be using this for, it does NOT need dataEncipherment. Also for HTTPS you should set the domainname(s) and/or address(es) used for the server in SAN/SubjectAlternativeName; if you don't (at least) Chrome and Edge will not accept it, although curl (for all libs I know about) will if CommonName in Subject (which keytool misleadingly prompts as "First and Last Name") matches.